# How many levels are allowed in AWS IoT-Core Topics? Is it possible to increase it?

Tags: aws-iot

I am working in a project where the topics are more than 8 levels. I just realize that when I try to publish a 9 level topics `T0/T1/T2/T3/T4/T5/T6/T7/T8` the `AWS IoT-Core test` throws an error: `Error Code 8 - AMQJS0008I Socket closed`:

[image]

But if I reduce to `8 levels topic (T0-T7)` everything works good. **I am supposing 8 levels are the limit**.

[image]

The [AWS official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/topics.html) doesn't show how many topics are allowed in this broker or how we can increase it if possible.
I didn't find this limit not even for a [regular MQTT broker](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-5-mqtt-topics-best-practices/), that could give me a clue about AWS.

So, does someone know how many levels are allowed or how to increase this - if possible in AWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limit of 8 topic levels or 7 forward slashes. This is documented under the Protocols limits at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/iot-core.html#limits_iot

> Maximum number of slashes in topic and topic filter
>
> A topic in a publish or subscribe request can have no more than 7 forward slashes (/). This excludes the first 3 slashes in the mandatory segments for Basic Ingest topics ($AWS/rules/rule-name/).

I have not seen any documentation that states that this limit can be increased.